# computer turns on then goes in to standby

Tags: troubleshooting, desktop-computer

I have recently taken my graphics card, memory, card reader, cd and possibly my hard disk out the case.

I have now put them back. But now when I turn the computer back on a fan spins (for a second ish) and tue power light comes on but nothing else happens. Apart from tue power light flicking on and off in three second intervals.(nothing shows up on the monitor at any point)

What steps can I take to start trouble shooting this?

It is a compaq presario, if that helps

Comment: You have possibly taken the hard drive out of the case? You aren't certain whether or not you actually took the hard drive out?

Comment: Why did you take components out of the PC in the first place? Was there already an issue?

Comment: @CharlieRB I took it apart to try and learn more abouthow Iit all works etc...Iits an old pc so wasnt to bothered about breaking it, lessone learnt :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing all the parts from your computer, then turning it on and seeing if it works.  Gradually add each part back and see when the problem recurs.

Another thing to do is to reset the BIOS (if you can get into it).  If you have multiple memory sticks, and none of the above works, try moving one of them, then putting it back and remove the other.

If that fails, try a new PSU !!!

Comment: It was an issue with the memory sticks not being in properly